# GAE doesn't import gflags

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client, gflags

I'm trying to get oauth to work on Google App Engine (GAE), but I'm unable to import the `OAuth2Decorator`, because it tries to import `gflags` and fails.

In command line I've ran `help('modules')` and gflags is listed, and I've ran `import os` + `import gflags` + `print os.path.dirname(gflags.__file__)` and received `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/python_gflags-2.0-py2.7.egg`.

In GAE Dev Console I've ran:

```
import sys
import os

try:
  import webapp2
  import httplib2
  from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator 

except ImportError, e:
  print("The import failed!")
  print(e)
```

and received:

```
The import failed!
No module named gflags
```

`gflags` is imported by `from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator`, but GAE fails to import `gflags` every time I run the code.

I'm not sure it makes a difference, but I'm running Mac OS 10.7.5 and python 2.7.1

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I just recently updated the installation instructions with App Engine specific instructions:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation

There is a download specifically for App Engine that contains all the client library code *and* dependencies, just unzip that file into your project and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm not using appengine and  just need oauth client library on my server. I'm still getting this error after following the non-appengine specific instructions on the page. This is a bit frustrating.

Comment: This reoccured for me.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the required library files to your App Engine project. From the [client library docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine), once you've installed the client library run:

```
$ enable-app-engine-project your_app_directory
```

Comment: I ran that command and I gave me an error saying oauth2client already existed in the directory, which it did because I manually put it there, so I deleted it and reran the command. The problem is that it only copied the `__init__.py` file into the new `oauth2client` directory, and not the rest of the `oauth2client` files, such as the `app engine.py` file. I tried reinstalling `oauth2client` but that didn't work, so I've just manually replaced the folder. Should I have to manually add the files or should it copy all of them over?